# Map function on Pandas dataframe is slow when changing a value with mutliprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to multiprocess a function being applied to a pandas dataframe using the map function. I can return the result, turn that into a list and create a new column in the data frame using the list, and that happens quickly. If, however, I try to directly change a cell in the dataframe, the function slows down significantly.

Is there a faster way to change a cell directly? Or should I just return a map and change the dataframe column with that map?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def function1(a):
    return a**2

def function2(a):
    train['result'] = a**2 

pool            = Pool(processes=4)
result_list     = pool.map(function1, train['id'])
results         = list(result_list)
train['result'] = results


%timeit pool.map(function1, train['id'])
%timeit pool.map(function2, train['id'])

1 loop, best of 3: 689 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 34.4 s per loop
```

Comment: How do you think you benefits from have 4 processes adjusting the SAME DataFrame column?

Comment: Each row of the dataframe contains an integer sequence which I'll by applying a few different non trivial functions to, eg linear regression. Their output will sometimes be added to another column of the dataframe. They're all independent, so I assume that running multiple parallel processes will be faster than calculating them sequentially in one process.

Comment: Are you on Windows.mac or linux?

Comment: Linux Mint 17, although I could run in Windows

Comment: No, dont ever run mutliprocess on Windows. The OS does not have .fork()  which make you effort a waste.

Comment: That's good to know! I didnt' mention this, but the multiprocessing works. I only left that in my code in case it was relevant to my issue.

Comment: I would test your code without mutli- processing to compare and it could be .map thats slowing this down.. - I dont use  pool.map... Also, I would not spend to much time on local optimization.

Comment: Same issue without the multiprocessing, even bigger difference in time. You're probably right though, I'll just move on. I just thought there may be a better solution.